# Primefaces row editing not working properly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to perform row editing on primefaces datatable.I am fetching all the values of the datatable from database.In onEdit method i am just trying to fetch the primary key value of the row being edited .When i try to edit or cancel edit on clicking the tick or cross marks i am  getting following exception.I am a newbie in JSF,please help on how to do row editing which can update the values to database.

Exception that i get

> Aug 22, 2013 3:56:56 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
>   INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:51)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:40)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:57)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
>       at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:228)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:507)
>       at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>       at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:639)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:377)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
>       at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My JSF code snippet

```xml
<h:form id="lpcForm">

    <div id="content">      
        <p:dataTable var="lpcData" value="#{lpcBean.lpcIdList}" id="lpcList"
            editable="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1110"
            tableStyle="table-layout:auto; width:1130px;" scrollHeight="330"
            styleClass="datatable">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{lpcBean.onEdit}" />

            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{lpcBean.onCancel}" />

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%" />


            <p:column headerText="LPC ID" style="width:20%">
                <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.LPCID}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="First Name" style="width:20%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.name_First}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{lpcData.name_First}" style="width:100%"
                            label="firstName" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Last Name" style="width:24%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.name_Last}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{lpcData.name_Last}" style="width:100%"
                            label="lastName" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Email" style="width:20%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.email_Address}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{lpcData.email_Address}" style="width:100%"
                            label="emailAddress" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Region" style="width:24%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.region}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{lpcData.region}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lpcBean.regions}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="State" style="width:24%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.homeState}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{lpcData.homeState}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lpcBean.mainStates}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Profit Center" style="width:20%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.profitCenter}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{lpcData.profitCenter}" style="width:100%"
                            label="profitCenter" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>



            <p:column headerText="Active" style="width:24%">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.active_LPC}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{lpcData.active_LPC}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lpcBean.activeLpcs}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:6%">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

My Managed bean snippet

```java
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class LpcBean implements Serializable {

    private List<LPC>lpcItems=new ArrayList<LPC>();
    public static LPC[] selectedRows; 
    public static LPC itemSelect;
    private LpcDataModel lpcIdList;
    Connection connection;
    Statement selectStmt1,selectStmt2,selectStmt3,selectStmt4;
    private List<String> nameList;
    private String selectedLpcName;
    private String selectedItem; 
    private List<String> regions=new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String>mainStates=new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String>activeLpcs=new ArrayList<String>();
    public LpcBean() {
        System.out.println("inside the constructor");
        lpcIdList = new LpcDataModel(lpcItems); 
        getLpcFields();
    }


    public List<LPC> getLpcItems() {
        return lpcItems;
    }


    public void setLpcItems(List<LPC> lpcItems) {
        this.lpcItems = lpcItems;
    }


    public LPC[] getSelectedRows() {
        return selectedRows;
    }

    public void setSelectedRows(LPC[] selectedRows) {
        LpcBean.selectedRows = selectedRows;
    }


    public LpcDataModel getLpcIdList() {
        return lpcIdList;
    }


    public void setLpcIdList(LpcDataModel lpcIdList) {
        this.lpcIdList = lpcIdList;
    }


    public String getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(String selectedItem) {
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    public List<String> getNameList() {
        return nameList;
    }


    public void setNameList(List<String> nameList) {
        this.nameList = nameList;
    }



    public String getSelectedLpcName() {
        return selectedLpcName;
    }


    public void setSelectedLpcName(String selectedLpcName) {
        this.selectedLpcName = selectedLpcName;
    }



    public void getLpcFields() {

        try
        {

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://cvgapp106I/dev2_LPSR");

            System.out.println("connected to the database");

            selectStmt1 = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = selectStmt1.executeQuery("select * from LPC order by LPCID");


            while(rs1.next()){


                lpcItems.add(new LPC(rs1.getString("LPCID"),rs1.getString("Name_First"),
                rs1.getString("Name_Last"),rs1.getString("Email_Address"),rs1.getString("Region"),
                rs1.getString("HomeState"),rs1.getString("ProfitCenter"),rs1.getString("Active_LPC")));


            }
            selectStmt2=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2=selectStmt2.executeQuery("Select * from Tbl_state");


            while(rs2.next())
            {
                mainStates.add(rs2.getString("State"));

            }
            selectStmt3=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs3=selectStmt3.executeQuery("Select * from Tbl_Regional_Managers");

            while(rs3.next())
            {
                regions.add(rs3.getString("Location"));
            }
            selectStmt4=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs4=selectStmt4.executeQuery("Select * from YesNo");



            while(rs4.next())
            {
                activeLpcs.add(rs4.getString("YesNo_Key"));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println("Error Data : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {

                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    public void setRegions(List<String> regions) {
        this.regions = regions;
    }


    public void setMainStates(List<String> mainStates) {
        this.mainStates = mainStates;
    }


    public void setActiveLpcs(List<String> activeLpcs) {
        this.activeLpcs = activeLpcs;
    }


    public List<String> getRegions() {
        return regions;
    }


    public List<String> getMainStates() {
        return mainStates;
    }


    public List<String> getActiveLpcs() {
        return activeLpcs;
    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {


        String lpcId=(String) ((LPC) event.getObject()).getLPCID();
        System.out.println("EMAIL ID:"+lpcId);

    }

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {

        System.out.println("inside on cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is your PF version? Have you tried with less complex table (for example a single editable column)? Have you tried changing the DB connection for a list populated by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops!!!I missed selection attribute in for the datatable.Now it is working fine.

```
 <p:dataTable var="lpcData" value="#{lpcBean.lpcIdList}" selection="#{lpcBean.selectedRows}" 
              id="lpcList" editable="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="1110"
              tableStyle="table-layout:auto; width:1130px;" scrollHeight="330" 
              styleClass="datatable">
```